# Using a CradlePoint router with ROS

Tags: ros, communication, network

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am working on a project that requires long range communication using a cell network. We have a 4G modem with a static IP address that is attached to a CradlePoint CTR-500 router. This router is then linked into the robot's computer through eth0. While the static IP address is in the 66._ _ _. _ _ *. _ _ _ range, the CradlePoint creates a LAN in the 192.168.0.* _ _ subnet, and this is what the computer views its IP address as.

I have a base station located far away that is connected to the internet. I can ping the USB modem from the base station, and the robot's computer can ping the base station, but I cannot connect to each of them through ROS. I imagine that I will have to set up some sort of port forwarding to get them to communicate.

If anyone has any suggestions on how I can connect the two computers through ROS, I would greatly appreciate it.

Thank you,

-Joe

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/31078/using-a-cradlepoint-router-with-ros/) by [Joe](https://answers.ros.org/users/1318/joe/) on ROS Answers with karma: 85 on 2012-04-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Go through the [tutorials](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials) and there are tutorials on how to do that. Also double check your router's firewall isn't blocking the ports that ROS is trying to use.

---

Originally posted by [Kevin](https://answers.ros.org/users/186/kevin/) with karma: 2962 on 2012-04-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1